# Refactoring ASP.NET control names

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, refactoring

I have an ASP.NET page with a code-behind file (`.ascx` file in the solution explorer, with `.ascx.cs` and `.ascx.designer.cs` files under it) I need to rename lots of controls on the page. If I change the ID in the properties pane in the designer window, it doesn't change it in the code file, and all references to the control are marked as an unrecognized name. If I change it in the code file (using the built-in refactoring), it changes it all over the code file, but not in the designer.

How can I refactor it across the whole project?

Comment: There is a tool in Visual Studio: Find and Replace :-)  I haven't had the issue with the designer.  If I change the ID of a control in the markup, the designer usually updates.  You could try switching to design mode in the markup, to see if that will force the designer to update.

Comment: @BrianMains It is not the markup, but rather the C# code that is not updated. I need to change names of 100+ controls (I didn't write the original and it was done very badly with lots of `TextBox1` etc.) Having to do it *twice* for each name (once in the designer/markup and once in the code) is quite a chore.

Comment: yes, I understand the pain.  I'm sure there are instances of FindControl("ID") in there too to make it even worse.  I personally don't know of a tool to do this... maybe Resharper or Telerik's JustCode has something.

Comment: @BrianMains Thank you for the tip on `FindControl()`. I would of totally missed those.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a build in way to do that. But you can try if [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can to that. It has powerful refactoring tools and is worth a look. Sorry, I have no asp project to test it myself.

Comment: Do you know of a free tool to do this?

Comment: You can register for an open source license of ReSharper which is free. To test if it works you can use the trial period.